# Unable to reindex product flat data

Tags: database, reindex

im new to magento

I have magento installation ( magento 1.9.1 , MySQL 5.5.40-36.1 , PHP:
5.4.38 , Apache:
2.2.29 ) im unable to reindex my product flat data from the magento backend and  my magento search is also not working.

for the 1st part i have tried all the methods give in this blog 
http://webexplorar.com/magento-reindexing-problems-solutions/

have tried doing it by truncating catalog_Product_flat_data and then re indexing it , also tried reindexer script, when i used this script i got this error -

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table 'studentb_one.#sql-7ecb_1ea14b6' (errno: 121)' in /home4/studentb/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228 
Stack trace: #0 /home4/studentb/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php(228): PDOStatement->execute(Array) 
#1 /home4/studentb/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array) 
#2 /home4/studentb/public_html/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home4/studentb/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array) 
#4 /home4/studentb/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array) 
#5 /home4/studentb/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('ALTER TABLE `ca...', Array) 
#6 /home4/studentb/public_html/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(347): Varien_Db_Adapt in /home4/studentb/public_html/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php on line 228
```

also have tried switching the search types in the magento backend

have read about the foreign key disable and enable , can that also solve this issue.

please help...

also  want to know what is this error and upon solving this error will the search work properly??

Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you exactly doing to get this error? This error should appear anytime you try to load your site, not just when re-indexing.

Comment: well i was trying a bunch of things for reindexing, i got this error when i ran an indexing script   " <?php  
require_once 'app/Mage.php';  
$app = Mage::app('admin');  
umask(0);  
for ($index = 1; $index <= 8; $index++) {  
     $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($index);  
     $process->reindexAll();  
}
?>"

Comment: What happens when you load your website on the browser, go to the admin panel, etc.?

Comment: it loads perfectly fine , all the products active products and categories

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an extension installation script rather than an indexing problem. However, from your comment, it also seems like perhaps there's an extension that creates a table when you reindex (possibly just a temporary table for reindexing).

In any case, one of your extensions is trying to install a table called `#sql-7ecb_1ea14b6` (what a strange name for a table) with a foreign key constraint whose name is identical to another FK constraint. You'll need to change this name in the script that installs `#sql-7ecb_1ea14b6`.

1. Find out which extension has this installation script or tries to create this table.
2. Look in the `sql` directory and find the script that tries to install that table. Alternatively, find the extension and search for anything resembling below. Note the name in the following section..

   CONSTRAINT `THIS_IS_THE_FOREIGN_KEY_CONTRAINT_NAME` FOREIGN KEY (`some_column`) REFERENCES `some_table` (`another_column`)...
3. Do a string search on your entire `app` directory and find out the other extension that already used this name.

You can also run the following query to see all of the contraints. `THIS_IS_THE_FOREIGN_KEY_CONTRAINT_NAME` should already be present in this list.

```
SELECT constraint_name,table_name
FROM information_schema.table_constraints 
WHERE constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' 
    AND table_schema = DATABASE() 
ORDER BY constraint_name;
```

Note: I suspect there may be other problems, but this should fix your immediate issue.

Comment: i tried searching but the search on the data base came empty, im trying the string search on the sql directory of this table name #sql-7ecb_1ea14b6

Comment: This is all I can give you with the information I have. I updated my answer slightly.